# How to install "Indigo" when my PC is "kinetic"? I would like to change distro

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On this time, I found some tool problem on kinetic and  I would like to uninstall Kinetic and install indigo. How to do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248870/how-to-install-%22indigo%22-when-my-pc-is-%22kinetic%22?-i-would-like-to-change-distro./) by [Chucolate](https://answers.ros.org/users/28340/chucolate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking for older Q&As is definitely good, but the one @abrzozowski linked is a bit old and the answer leaves an important bit of information implied: yes, you can install multiple ROS versions on a single OS, *but*, there need to be multiple ROS releases for that OS available.

Kinetic is available for Ubuntu Wily and Xenial ([REP-3 - Platforms by Distribution - Kinetic Kame](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#kinetic-kame-may-2016-may-2021)).

Indigo is available for Ubuntu Saucy & Trusty ([REP-3 - Platforms by Distribution - Indigo Igloo](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#indigo-igloo-may-2014)).

There is no release of ROS Indigo for any OS that supports ROS Kinetic, so @Chucolate will either have to downgrade from Ubuntu Xenial (16.04) to Ubuntu Trusty (14.04), or attempt a source build of ROS Indigo on Ubuntu Xenial.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1